# Delete helm chart from *registry* (not uninstall from cluster; not repository)

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm, docker-registry

Helm v3 supports OCI registries, such as (for example) the standard `registry` image as installed with [`docker run -dp 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry`](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/) as opposed to the more common v2 [repositories](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_repository/).

I can push, pull, etc, but I don't see any simple way to *delete* an obsolete chart from the registry once it's there.

Anyone got a good suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to be sure your registry allows the deletion API, there's an extra `REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED` option for that:

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped --name registry \
  -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/var/lib/registry" \
  -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true" \
  -v "registry-data:/var/lib/registry" \
  -p "127.0.0.1:5000:5000" \
  registry:2
```

Then you can call the [manifest delete API](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md#deleting-manifests). Just note that this will delete all tags pointing to that manifest. If you want to delete a single tag without impacting other tags to the same manifest, my own [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/) project includes a `regctl tag rm` command for deleting a single tag, along with other CLI's you may find useful for managing a local registry (similar projects include crane and skopeo but I'm not sure they offer tag deletion).

Once you delete a manifest, the registry itself will still have some underlying blobs that can be pruned with a periodic GC. This should be done when no writes are occurring on the registry:

```
docker exec registry /bin/registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml --delete-untagged
```

Comment: And registries I do not own and control that do not have this set simply disallow deletions, yes? Do you know if a jFrog artifactory (which is supposed to be oci:// compliant) is the same?

Comment: @PaulHodges If the registry doesn't permit the API, there's not a lot you can do. Docker Hub has their own registry specific API. Registries can disable APIs, returning a permission denied, and still be OCI compliant, so no idea if Artifactory enables this out of the box.